# How do I use the 2d-extras zip-file in my project? (or any other external unity download for that matter)

Tags: unity-game-engine

Sorry, I know this is probably a dumb question, but I can't figure out how to import and use the 2d-extras scripts in my project. I want to use the Rule and Animated tiles but all the tutorials I'm following seem to be for an older version of Unity. I'm using 2019.3.8f1 and all the tutorials say to just unzip and drag what I want into my assets folder but doing that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I figured out! I was right, it was a stupid question. It's literally in the readme. If anyone else is wondering, all you have to do is put the folder inside of the Project/packages folder and then copy the line -- "com.unity.2d.tilemap.extras": "https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/2d-extras.git#master" into the manifest.json -- under dependencies which is also in the packages folder.

Answer (score 0):

there is another way to do that, After downloading the repository from github, you can create a "com.unity.2d.tilemap.extras" folder in the "Packages" file of the project you are working with and copy all the files in the zip you downloaded from github to this "com.unity.2d.tilemap.extras" folder. When you restart your project, you can define the ruletile and animated tiles as you want.